# echo $data[ ] for specific row from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to output the name associated to a specific ID value in a mySQL database but it doesn't work. The loaded id row is defined in a get_id.php file. Am I missing something or is something in the code wrong ?

here is the html part with Ajax:

```html
<html>

<head>

<script>
function showHint(id) {
    if (id.value == 0) {
        document.getElementById("name-display").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("name-display").innerHTML = <?php echo $data['name'];?>
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_id.php?id=" + id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<p><b>Enter ID here</b></p>
<form>
ID: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Name: <span id="name-display"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

get_id.php file:

```html
<?php
    require 'database.php';

        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pokemons where id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        Database::disconnect();
    
?>
```

Comment: is it the query or Ajax at issue?

Comment: @smith I think the issue comes from the get_id.php file

Comment: get_id.php does not output anything

Comment: @smith I know but the loaded row is set in this file. So if something is missing or wrong in it nothing is loaded in the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the printing of the data is wrong you must 
Echo the retrived data in the get_id.php print the results in there and change the script like this

```
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("name-display").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
```

Now everything should works fine but don't forget to echo the result using a while in the php file